# Write Unicode String In a File Using StreamWriter doesn't Work

Tags: c#, .net, stream, streamwriter

I have this code:

```
string s = "آ";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("a.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteLine(s);
```

but when I run it I can't see any "آ" in a.txt!! There isn't any string in a.txt! It is Empty!  What is problem!?! Can anyone help me???

Comment: What _do_ you see? What are you using to open the file?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You never `Close()` the `StreamWriter`.

If you call `writer.Close()` when you finish writing, you will see the character.

But, since it implements `IDisposable` you should wrap the creation of the `StreamWriter` in a `using` statement:

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("a.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
   writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

This will close the stream for you.

Answer (score 5):

By the looks of it you're not [`Flush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx)ing or [`Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx)ing the `StreamWriter` before you end your application. `StreamWriter` uses a buffer internally which needs to be flushed before you close your application or the `StreamWriter` goes out of scope otherwise the data you wrote to it will not be written to disc.

You can call `Close()` once you're done - although instead I would suggest using a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement instead to also assure that your `StreamWriter` gets properly disposed.

```
string s = "آ";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("a.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `File.WriteAllText("a.txt", s, Encoding.UTF8);`.

Answer (score 0):

Few tips:

- do you see any character in the file written in place of one you expect? If not you're not flushing and closing the stream
- StreamWriter should be able to write unicode without you having to choose encoding, but you could try to use UTF32 encoding.

Check [How to: Write Text to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Follow, complete function for export a listview to excel with correct special characteres:

```
private void Exportar()
    {
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Arquivo Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "logs";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Exportar para Excel";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ColumnHeader ch in lstPesquisa.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append(ch.Text + "\t");
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lstPesquisa.Items)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvs in lvi.SubItems)
            {
                if (lvs.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                {
                    sb.Append(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    string ITEM = Regex.Replace(lvs.Text, @"\t|\n|\r", "");//remover novas linhas
                    sb.Append(ITEM + "\t");
                }
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        DialogResult dr = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName, false, Encoding.UTF32);
            sw.Write(sb.ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file from somewhere that contains these Unicode characters then you do some modifications and write back to the file, the problem arises. I was stuck with the same problem. Here is the solution that worked for me

Reading data from a file that contains Unicode characters

```
List<string>fileData= File.ReadAllLines("URPath",Encoding.Default).ToList());
//Any modifications
File.WriteAllLines("URPath", hstFileData,Encoding.Default);
```

I know this is not pretty but it worked.
hope this helps!